# How to increase disk space in Wubi (Ubuntu via windows)?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu-9.04, wubi

I installed Ubuntu via Windows 7. I allocated only 8 GB space to it, but unfortunately now I want more space without reinstalling or creating another partition. Is there any way to increase the disk space in the Ubuntu? Please help me to figure it out ?

Answer (score 2):

According to this [guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How%20do%20I%20resize%20the%20virtual%20disks?), you can use [LVPM](http://lubi.sourceforge.net/lvpm.html)

As an alternative, you can use the following script to move /home to a dedicated virtual disk.

Download [wubi-add-virtual-disk](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=wubi-add-virtual-disk), open a terminal and run:

```
sudo sh wubi-add-virtual-disk /home 15000
```

Where the first argument is the directory to move to a new dedicated disk, and the second argument is the size in MB.

You should now reboot. If you are happy with the result, you can now remove /home.backup. To undo the changes remove /home, copy rename /home.backup to /home and remove the /home line in /etc/fstab.