# How to increase memory allocation to Ubuntu Linux OS?

Tags: memory, ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to increase disk space in Wubi (Ubuntu via windows)?](https://superuser.com/questions/125990/how-to-increase-disk-space-in-wubi-ubuntu-via-windows)

I have installed Ubuntu linux operating system inside Windows Vista OS. Initially i allocated 11 GB to it but now i want to allocate more space to it **without un-installing** it. Is there is any way to do it ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to repartition your disk?  If that's the case, take it to http://superuser.com

Comment: `memory != disk`

Answer (score 0):

You would first have to partition your hard disk in Windows OS using the Disk Manager found in Administrative Tools.

After partitioning your hard disk (But don't format it to NTFS!) you boot to your Ubuntu OS and simple using the "fdisk -l" command to find your newly created partition. Then after finding it, use "fdisk " to format and mount your partition. Don't forget to use the "partprobe" command after you exit from the "fdisk command"!!! All these commands are used in the terminal.